# How to clear iconBadge using Local Notification in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding clear icon badge

My code is like this

```
 UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
        content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Elon said:"
                                                              arguments:nil];
        content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello Tom！Get up, let's play with Jerry!"
                                                             arguments:nil];
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

        // 4. update application icon badge number
        content.badge = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1)];
        // Deliver the notification in five seconds.
        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                                      triggerWithTimeInterval:5.f
                                                      repeats:NO];
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecond"
                                                                              content:content
                                                                              trigger:trigger];
        /// 3. schedule localNotification
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"add NotificationRequest succeeded!");
            }
        }];
```

To create local notification

To clear notification I am using code like this

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
    [center removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
    content.badge = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber * 0)];


}
```

But using this code badge is not getting clear.How to clear badge?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

In swift:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

}
```

Objective C:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: I am using Objective C.Please share code regarding to Objective C.